# How to shorten a sentence while keeping the same meaning and impact?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I have the following sentence:

> Whether you are a software developer or a recruiter, sign up now to
>   gain access to the best recruitment network!

I feel this is too long for a subheading and is trying to find a way to address this sentence in a more concise manner.

If this be of interest to you, the headline is

> A New Way to Hire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

> Developers and recruiters: sign up now for the best recruitment network!

Comment: Sounds great. Do you feel this would complement well my headline A New Way to Hire

Comment: I think it would work, although since your headline says "Hire" and not "Find a Job", it seems that your target audience is more recruiters than developers.

Comment: If my target market is more hiring manager and developers, do you feel it would best if my headline was thus A New Way to Find a Job?

Comment: I notice that you queried a downvote on another thread (though the answer was fine by the time I got to it). However, here, please note that this question is soliciting writing advice rather than asking about English grammar say. It is off-topic, and answering it just encourages similar questions.